# rate stretch tool on premier

Tags: premiere

I have made a sequence on adobe premier. One of the clips I have stretched using the stretch rate tool and another I have compressed using the same tool.

I have made sure the clips are video blended. However when I render the sequence into a QuickTime movie the clips I've slowed down and speed up are green and damaged. Does anyone please know why this is and how I can fix it? Many thanks

Comment: Do you know what codec the clips are?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you forgot to change framerate of composition.

Comment: Thanks how do I change the frame rate of the composition please?

Comment: Via composition settings. Right click on composition, and there "Composition Settings."

Comment: The framerate of the composition won't make the clips "green and damaged", and changing the frame rate will affect all the other non-stretched clips. I really don't see how that would be a solution to this problem.